# Не могу обратиться к элементу массива string C#

Tags: c#

Уже упростил эту часть кода до невозможного, но всё равно выдаёт ошибку:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Указывая на строку с присвоением значения.

```
string[,] Table = new string[Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2, 2)) + 1, 2 + 1];
Table[0, 0] = "A";
```

Вот полный код, здесь ругается на строку  for (int col = 0; col < count; col++)

```
public string[,] MakeTable(List<char> vars, int count)
        {
            string[,] Table = new string[Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2, count)) + 1, count + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) Table[0, i] = Convert.ToString(vars[i]);
            Table[0, count + 1] = "F";
            for (int col = 0; col < count; col++)
            {
                for (int row = 1; row < Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2, count)); row++)
                {
                    if (col == 0)
                    {
                        if (row % 2 == 0) Table[row, col] = "0";
                        else Table[row, col] = "1";
                    }
                    if (col == 1)
                    {
                        if (row % 4 < 2) Table[row, col] = "0";
                        else Table[row, col] = "1";
                    }
                    if (col == 2)
                    {
                        if (row % 8 < 4) Table[row, col] = "0";
                        else Table[row, col] = "1";
                    }
                    if (col == 3)
                    {
                        if (row % 16 < 8) Table[row, col] = "0";
                        else Table[row, col] = "1";
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 1; i < Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2, count)); i++)
            {
                Table[i, count + 1] = "2";
            }
            return Table;
        }
        private void Generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string exp = Textbox.Text;
            int count = 0;
            List<char> vars = new List<char>();
            foreach (char el in exp)
            {
                bool u = false;
                if (Char.IsLetter(el))
                {
                    foreach (char i in vars) if (el == i) u = true;
                    if (u == false)
                    {
                        count++;
                        vars.Add(el);
                    }
                }
            }
            string[,] Table = MakeTable(vars, count);
        }
```

Comment: Друже, это весь код? или он находится в цикле? индексы считаются от 0 до n-1. т.е. по формуле выходит что создается масив string[5,3] т.е и индtксы будут [0-4,0-2], лучше добавь код целиком

Comment: В том то и дело что цикла нет, как и написал уже упростил как мог, это весь код в начале метода. Но всё равно выдает ошибку

Comment: смотри обращения к другим массивам, либо поставь точку остановы и пошагово смотри обращение к массиву, только что проверил две эти строки кода в компиляторе, значение в массиве проставилось

Comment: Хоть убей не могу найти ошибку. На данный момент я хочу чтобы при получении строки "a&b" у меня была таблица (мой двумерный массив) такого вида: a b F\n 0 0 2\n 1 0 2\n 0 1 2\n 1 1 2 Код сейчас добавлю.

Comment: я же говорил что дело в инексах, в методе MakeTable в самом конце где ты обращаешься к массиву **Table[i, count + 1}**, ты объявил массив с count+1 и обращаешься так же, а индексы всегда считаются от 0, т.е. второй индес массива будет равняться **count**

Comment: Исправил на Table[i, count] = "2"; Всё равно ругается на ту же строку

Comment: Смотрите на строки, где у вас индекс `Table[0, count + 1] = "F";`, он у вас в двух местах, сверху и снизу. Когда вы задаете таблицу размером к примеру `[9+1]`, то индексы у вас будут `0..9`, а не count + 1 = 9 + 1 = 10 = ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо, этой ошибки больше нет

Comment: на будущее, если создаешь массив по параметрам, 'array[count]' то и обращайся к массиву через циклы 'for(int i=0; i < count;i++)' количество элементов в массиве всегда = count, но индексы от 0 до count-1 и условия цикла как-раз проходят от 0 (int i =0) до count -1 ( i < count) т.е. пока i меньше count как только i = count то цикл прекращает счёт

Comment: Поправили-бы вы огромное количество `if` на `switch-case`. Гораздо ведь приятнее б стало выглядеть, а то, что внутри - можно сократить до `Table[row, col] = (row % 2 == 0) ? "0" : "1"` (сделал только для 1 с if. дальше по аналогии)

Comment: Так же, заметил, что вы 3 раза аж вычисляете `Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2, count)`. Почему-бы не хранить это в переменной и обращаться к ней, а не вычислять каждый раз заново? Вроде, мелочь, но бросается сильно в глаза. Просто создайте переменную и дайте ей говорящее имя и обращайтесь к ней, а не используйте один и тот же код каждый раз